# Ionic app doesn't show custom buttons from Highchart library

Tags: ionic-framework, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I am developing an application with Ionic 1.3.1 and the Highcharts library.
My problem is how  can i add custom buttons to the charts?.
I have added to the json object the exporting option, but when I execute the app in an  Android/IOS device  the buttons don't show and I don't know why. 
This is the highcharts code:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false,
        type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser market shares'
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            showInLegend: true
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
            y: 56.33
        }, {
            name: 'Chrome',
            y: 24.03,
            sliced: true,
            selected: true
        }, {
            name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
            y: 0.2
        }]
    }],
    exporting: {
        buttons: {
            printButton: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exportButton: {
                enabled: false
            },
            custom: {
                symbol: 'diamond',
                symbolFill: '#B5C9DF',
                hoverSymbolFill: '#779ABF',
                _titleKey: 'printButtonTitle',
                onclick: function() {
                    alert('click!')
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Your code is not complete and it does not allow to reproduce the issue. Can you create a live example e.g. on codepen? Did you include exporting module to the app? http://jsfiddle.net/qyvb2yhg/

Comment: The button tag is rendered on the browser at least?

Comment: The button tag is not rendered on the browser. If you execute the code in an angular app, the browser render the button, but if execute the code in the ionic app not.

Answer (score 0):

To implement customs buttons is neccesary import the file *'highcharts/modules/exporting.js'* from the Highcharts library.